# SPSS Python writing variable list to excel

Tags: python, excel, list, spss

Is it possible to write, from SPSS, (using Python), into a newly created Excel file, the variable list and variable labels?

Comment: Take a look at this [SPSS Dictionary tool](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/create-dictionary-dataset/) too. It does almost exactly what you're looking for. Pasting its syntax is the perfect starting point for further tweaking.

Comment: a, brilliant! How did I miss that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lookup [`DISPLAY DICTIONARY`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_display_overview.htm) and/or [`CODEBOOK`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_codebook.htm). It would then be a case of exporting these outputs (from SPSS's output viewer) to Excel  (`OUTPUT EXPORT` command).

If you needed something more customized then you can either capture the output via OMS and do manipulations as you please (and then export to Excel) or you can use python APIS directly to retrieve variable, value labels and then write results to Excel (using any Python/Excel library of your choice such as xlrd or xlsxwriter, to name a couple).

The latter requires much more programming knowledge whereas the former can all be done with native SPSS syntax.

I have done something similar (producing a customized data dictionary) taking the Python programming approach and found this [module](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjPgarI6_DGAhXMWhQKHVLxCZY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fdeveloperworks%2Fcommunity%2Fforums%2Fajax%2Fdownload%2F77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014644856%2F09b5f231-7271-41b6-b9b8-ff58071089f2%2Fattachment_14644856_SPSSDataDictionary_201107.py&ei=h6awVY-iJMy1UdLip7AJ&usg=AFQjCNGDKiuUqRi4XhZzTYnvx1KbUgoVCg&sig2=qrY49nv2un2LZEKeAjRRJg&bvm=bv.98476267,d.ZGU&cad=rja) written by an unknown author very useful as a basis.

(Assuming you meant an automated way of achieving this else you could just copy and past the column of variable names and labels to Excel! Value labels can't be done similarly though for obvious reasons).

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for an automated way, since I am working with a lot of SPSS files whose structure needs to be exported. I am familiar with the codebook and display dictionary commands from SPSS, but I am not very familiar with python and exporting to excel. But thanks for the hints, I will investigate those further

Comment: I have edit the post to include a link to a module that you might find very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consult the discussion on
http://www.spssforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=12076
that also includes some python code (only for the variable labels but value labels are an easy extension, using the GetVariableLabel function. However, it depends a bit on how you want to have them, though. (on separate lines, or as following the variable.)

Answer (score 0):

You may also do it like so, followed by code of e.g. `openpyxl`:

```
from savReaderWriter import *

with SavHeaderReader(filename) as header:
    report = str(header) # txt report
    metadata = header.all()
```